# Facebook like button are not diplaying when anyone are liking the page and never are not showing for others

Tags: facebook-like

I want to add **facebook like button** to every pages.

But the problem is that the like button are showing first time when page are loading then if anyone are like the button then the like button are invisble.

I was test url into `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/`

here and getting the same problem. I am not getting any problem when i am testing with `http://fridaymedia.in/`

But when I am testing with

```
http://fridaymedia.in/TP_ECom/

http://fridaymedia.in/TP_ECom/retail/

http://fridaymedia.in/TP_ECom/retail/details/

http://fridaymedia.in/TP_ECom/retail/details/men-clothing-t-shirts/
```

They are getting the problem.

Please anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are your site's pages protected with an .htaccess password? If so, that could be the issue. I ran into this problem myself, and after going down the wrong path for a bit, I went back to my initial suspicion - htaccess password.

I didn't really look into the code, but I assume the button is set to have FB scrape the page after a user clicks like. With the password blocking things, FB can't scrape the page. Rather than displaying the button as if it hadn't been clicked, it just displays nothing - which is where my, and I assume your, confusion came in.

After changing htaccess, you'll have to wait 24 hours for the page(s) to be scraped by FB when they're loaded. However, you can use the FB debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to manually scrape individual pages.